# Average values in a column across several rows for each unique value in another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have three columns in a table: `ID`, `Field2` and `test_score`.
I don't care about `Field2` at the moment. I want to select every individual (based on their ID), and their **average** `test_score` so that the query comes back with one row per ID. How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: Use AVG function to calculate average and use GROUP BY function to get one row per ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, AVG(test_score) as average_score FROM tablename GROUP BY ID
```